# StackBrowser for Ubuntu Touch

Tags: app, javascript, qml

### About

StackBrowser allows you to explore the StackExchange network natively on Ubuntu Touch. Written in QML and JavaScript, it is mostly an excuse to play with the new [Ubuntu SDK](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/).

Currently you can:

- Browse and view recent questions
- Search questions by tag
- Browse, search, and view users
- Vote on questions and answers
- Add answers and comments

### Homepage

https://launchpad.net/stackbrowser

### Download

StackBrowser is available in the Ubuntu Touch Software Center. It can be tested on a 13.10 Ubuntu desktop system, or on earlier releases if you have the SDK installed, by grabbing its source from Launchpad.

```
bzr branch lp:stackbrowser
cd stackbrowser
qmlscene stackbrowser.qml
```

### Screenshots

[image: home screen]

[image: user view]

[image: tag browser]

Comment: It now supports posting comments with the write API.

Comment: Is this app still in active development? I would appreciate it! Unfortunately I can't find it in OpenStore?